# Multiclass prediction gives alternate classes in vowpal wabbit?

Tags: machine-learning, vowpalwabbit

Does the multiclass task in vowpal wabbit allow to get  a list  of  probable classes for a featureset. i.e instead of getting only the predicted label for a featureset , it is required that a list of labels be returned for that featureset sorted by probabilities. Is this possible in vowpal wabbit?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the only way to get multiclass probabilities in VW, is to use `--raw_predictions=file.txt` and convert the scores in file.txt to probabilities via logistic link function. You also need to use `--loss_function=logistic` when training, if you want to interpret the resulting scores (after applying logistic link) as probabilities.

(There are related options `--multilabel_oaa` and `--top`.)

**Update:**
Since [November 2015](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/pull/837), the easiest way how to obtain probabilities is to use `--oaa=N --loss_function=logistic --probabilities -p probs.txt`. (Or if you need label-dependent features: `--csoaa_ldf=mc --loss_function=logistic --probabilities -p probs.txt`.)